# Intent-filter for "content" uris like content://media/external/images/media/4711 only

Tags: android, image, android-contentprovider, intentfilter

I have written an imageviewer for local files that should also be started 
from gallery via a content-uri.

**My problem:**

How to define a manifest intent-filter that only matches uris like content://media/external/images/media/4711
but not http or https uris?

**What i already have:**

**(1)** A **working** filter for **local file** images (that is used to start the image view from a filemanager)

```
    <activity ... >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" android:scheme="file" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

**(2)** and a filter for all images that is **to broad** (including http, https, file, content) 
Unfortunatley my app cannont handle http(s) content :-(

```
    <activity ... >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

**(3)** What I have tried that **does not work** for uris like content://media/external/images/media/4711
My Test: using the "gallery" app-s share on an android 4.4 handset: my activity is not triggered.

```
    <activity ... >
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" android:scheme="content" />


            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Up to now i have tried these data elements that did not work:

```
        <data android:scheme="content" android:host="*"  />

        <data android:scheme="content" android:host="media" 
               android:pathPattern="/external/images/media/.*" />

        <data android:host="*" android:scheme="content" android:mimeType="image/*" />
```

Is there a way to get "content" only uris or "file" + "content" but not "http", "https", .... ?

Comment: Please reformat your code blocks. Add newlines so we do not have to scroll horizontaly.

Comment: i fixed it. I thougtht that that the category and action part was not that important for the problem/answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Standard image share intent:

```
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: It's clearly narrower than your too broad example. In what specific scenario does it fail?

Comment: you are right. send (without view) is narrower and should be enought for my app. unfortunately i have no permission to revoke my down-voting.

Comment: use `.*` instead `*`